# Desiring noun derived from "deride"

Tags: vocabulary, style

Example for "Blake's 7" fan(fic)s: "Avon said: 'My daily ??? of Vila is overdue.'" (EDITED for ambiguity)

"deride" as noun doesn't exist, so I have the choice of "deriding", "derision" and "derisement". If it is factually equivalent, choose the word Avon would choose :-/ <- Avon's legendary smirk

But the first looks like an ugly ad hoc gerundization-nounization to me, the third can be googled but I didn't find it in a dictionary, nor does "deridement" exist (and derisal you take against asthma). Go for the second?

Comment: The normal noun related to _deride_ is _derision_. I'm not familiar with the characters in question, but if Vila has the habit of making derisive comments, Avon could possibly coin the noun _deride_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: My brain knows. My fingers not. Corrected.

Comment: To me _derision_ looks fine assuming Vila makes derisive comments frequently. If Vila does not then another meaning can be sought. Can you edit in some insights into Vila's character?

Comment: I *do* know the characters, and I'd say Avon is the one who is more likely to be doing the deriding. Vila is the cowardly one, not the one who makes fun of the others.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Uh-oh. "de car - de schop! de schop - de car!", as Franz Fühmann outlined the word order problem in his famous German children book. So the genitive "Vila's derision" means "a derision dealt by Vila", not "a derision given to Vila"? Or is this an ambiguity? (Also could happen in German, word order or not...)

Comment: Ah I see you've updated the quote slightly. I think this removes the ambiguity, and the new phrasing weights the choice towards "deriding": "My daily deriding of Vila is overdue" sounds good, I don't think "derision" would work there.